# Fabric error - http error 504

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am getting error from fabric when tried to upload a new version.

> Archive distribution Error : -3 . Could not upload the distribution. The operation could not be completed (http error 504).

I have tried restarting fabric, but no luck.

Comment: I helped a coworker with a similar issue recently. We couldn't get the build to upload. We couldn't get it to work with the Fabric app so we set up Fastlane to upload the build. That might be worth a look. Its pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share the bundle id or package name of your app?

Comment: Hi Mike, Sure...is that possible to chat with you instead of sending it in public?